# Using fragment identifier to build redirectless navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to build a navigation which works and looks like on the [CakePHP documentation page](http://book.cakephp.org/) or google sites. What I mean by that:

1. The page navigation doesn't issue any redirects
2. The fragment/hash
   (#) symbol is not visible in the URLs and the address bar

I understand I should use the [fragment identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) to emulate the back button behaviour. I basically came up with a solution which covers the first point, simplified:

```
$.post("page", {urlId: hash}, function (data) {
  $("#content").html(data.content) // example
  // do some other stuff
}, "json");
```

However I am having difficulty with finding the solution for the second problem, which is my URLs look. I would like to use links which not contain the hash symbol. Now I have something like this:

http://example.com/#clients/john-doe

Which does not look like I want it:

http://example.com/clients/john-doe

I read somewhere that it is an URL translation task, not a jquery/javascript one.

Thank you for your answers.

EDIT: I don't need to care for older browsers as the project I am developing is going to be used only internally and it was agreed that maintaining support for older browsers is a waste of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history). But you will need to stick to hashes or regular links in older browsers.

There is an interesting project on github called [History.js](https://github.com/balupton/History.js/) that should abstract away the different "APIs".

Comment: Thank you, I think I'll use one of these solutions. But if anyone can explain how the whole mechanism of "omitting the hash" works I would be very grateful.